# How to make page scroll automatically to components when rendered using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to coding and been working with this simple portfolio page logic:

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-dawn-erkr9)

By using useRef and use effect hooks, I've got into a point in which the logic in child component scrolls the page to the most recent useRef value.

Now when the buttons are being pushed several times, the useRef value stops updating. For example, when the "things" button is pressed, it stays in that value and scrolls towards it with every button.

There's also a second problem in which the pages that are rendered on top of the homepage are being scrolled to top immediately without the scrollIntoView animation. Is there a way to lock a certain height when components are rendered on the top side?

Also, I'm aware of my bad habit of duplicating the same logic for every button and state. How could I work around this to make it more DRY?

Comment: I think you should try searching for the answer first

Comment: Can you check your code box, I did some editing if you can see. If not let me know I will paste here.

Comment: I can not see the editing. Would appreciate the paste!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created one method to change state, please let me know if there will be any confusion. Here you can see example for scrolling part [How to Scroll to Item in React](http://%20https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-scroll-to-item/).

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

import Portfolio from "./portfolio";
import Things from "./things";
import Contact from "./contact";
import About from "./about";

function App() {
  const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState({
    about: false,
    contact: false,
    portfolio: false,
    things: false
  });

  const showRuntimeContent = modelName => {
    if (modelName) {
      setShowContent({[modelName]: !showContent[modelName]});
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="home">


      <div className="container">
        <button onClick={() => showRuntimeContent("contact")}>Contacts</button>
        <button onClick={() => showRuntimeContent("portfolio")}>Portfolio</button>
        <button onClick={() => showRuntimeContent("about")}>About</button>
        <button onClick={() => showRuntimeContent("things")}>Things</button>

        <h1> HOME</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
      {showContent.contact ? <Contact /> : null}
      {showContent.portfolio ? <Portfolio /> : null}
      {showContent.about ? <About /> : null}
      {showContent.things ? <Things /> : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```